# Get value member from combo box

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, combobox

Done a fair bit of searching on this, but cannot find anything specific enough.

I am try to get the value member from my combobox, the reason being that the selected `valuemember` will form the basis of a query to populate a datagridview.

The below code looks at dbo.Calendar on a T-SQL database.  The column `month` is just the number for the month i.e. 1-12 and `MonthName` is as the name suggests.

Testing the `valuemember` output in the `MsgBox` command below, the output just gives me "month", rather than say "5" if the user selects "May" in the combobox.  Consequently, I am passing the string "Month" to try to populate my datagridview when I should be passing "5".  Anyone able to help on why I am not getting "5"?

```
Dim command As SqlCommand
        Dim adapter As New SqlDataAdapter()
        Dim ds As New DataSet()
        Dim sql As String
        sql = "select distinct month, MonthName from Calendar order by month asc"
        Try
            conn.Open()
            command = New SqlCommand(sql, conn)
            adapter.SelectCommand = command
            adapter.Fill(ds)
            adapter.Dispose()
            Command.Dispose()
            conn.Close()
            MonthSearch.DataSource = ds.Tables(0)
            MonthSearch.ValueMember = "month"
            MonthSearch.DisplayMember = "MonthName"
            MsgBox(MonthSearch.ValueMember)
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show("Cannot open connection! ")
        End Try
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `ValueMember` refers to the name of the column in the datatable which it is to use for the values.

The property you want to refer to is `SelectedValue`:

```
Option Infer On

Imports System.Data.SqlClient

Public Class Form1

    Sub SetUpMonthsCB()
        Dim dt As New DataTable

        Dim scsb As New SqlConnectionStringBuilder
        scsb.DataSource = ".\SQLEXPRESS"
        scsb.InitialCatalog = "testing"
        scsb.IntegratedSecurity = True

        Try
            Using sqlConn As New SqlConnection(scsb.ConnectionString)
                ' Here I used an existing table in my database, hence the different SQL.
                Dim sql = "SELECT DISTINCT M AS month, DATENAME(month, dt) AS MonthName FROM Calendar ORDER BY month ASC"
                Using da As New SqlDataAdapter(sql, sqlConn)
                    da.Fill(dt)
                End Using
            End Using
            MonthSearch.DataSource = dt
            MonthSearch.ValueMember = "month"
            MonthSearch.DisplayMember = "MonthName"

        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        End Try

        ' add the handler after populating the ComboBox to avoid unwanted firing of the event...
        AddHandler MonthSearch.SelectedIndexChanged, AddressOf MonthSearch_SelectedIndexChanged

    End Sub

    Private Sub MonthSearch_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
        Dim cb = DirectCast(sender, ComboBox)
        ' SelectedValue is an Object - you can get the name of its actual type with .SelectedValue.GetType().Name
        Dim val = CInt(cb.SelectedValue)
        MsgBox(val.ToString())

    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        SetUpMonthsCB()

    End Sub

End Class
```

The `SelectedValue` is returned as an object, but you can find its actual type with `SelectedValue.GetType()` - in this case it happened to be `Byte`, which can safely be converted to an `Integer`.

You don't need a full `DataSet` for the data - a `DataTable` will suffice.

A DataAdapter will open and close the connection for you.

If you use `Using`, that will take care of disposing of objects for you.

If you want to have a handler reacting to the `SelectedIndexChanged` event, it is better to add it after populating the ComboBox to avoid the event firing as the CB is populated.

Incidentally, if you only need to populate the ComboBox with {1..12},{"January"..."December"}, you can use something like

```
Dim dt = Enumerable.Range(1, 12).Select(Function(x) New With {.month = x, .MonthName = MonthName(x)}).ToList()
MonthSearch.DataSource = dt
MonthSearch.ValueMember = "month"
MonthSearch.DisplayMember = "MonthName"
```

Comment: Thanks Andrew,  that was a top class and informative response.  I particularly like your non-DB solution at the end, looks like an area I need to read up on a bit more.

Answer (score 1):

I guess the `MsgBox(MonthSearch.SelectedValue.ToString)` would do the work.

Comment: Thanks for responding with the correct property shadow :)

Answer (score 0):

You try simple solution:

Create Public Sub

```
Public Sub ListProfiles(cbo As ComboBox)
    Try
        Conn.Open()
        Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("List_JobProfiles", Conn)
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
        Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
        Dim ds As New DataSet
        da.SelectCommand = cmd
        ds.Clear()
        da.Fill(ds, 0)
        With cbo
            .DisplayMember = "ProName"
            .ValueMember = "ProID"
            .DataSource = ds.Tables(0)
        End With
        Conn.Close()
PROC_DONE:
    Catch ex As Exception
        Conn.Close()
        GoTo PROC_DONE
    End Try
End Sub
```

Event SelectedIndexChanged:

```
Private Sub cbJobProfiles_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cbJobProfiles.SelectedIndexChanged
    Dim cb = DirectCast(sender, ComboBox)
    Dim JobProfileID As Integer
    Dim i As Integer
    If Integer.TryParse(cb.SelectedValue.ToString, i) Then
        JobProfileID = cb.SelectedValue
    End If
    ListJobs(dgvJobs, JobProfileID)
End Sub
```

In Proc SQL Server:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE List_JobProfiles 
    AS
        BEGIN
            SELECT ProID, ProName, ProStatus FROM tblJobProfiles ORDER BY ProID ASC
        END
GO
```

Tested on VS 2019 and working for me
hope help to you

Comment: Very kind of you mate but this question was 4 years ago.